# Coalesce(), Nz() alternative in Access SQL 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, coalesce

I am trying to fetch null values but coalesce() and Nz() are not working.

```
select Nz(delay_head,0) from sumb where dep_reg = 'er'
```

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: Nz() is not working. I am trying to fetch NULL values and replace it with 0. How can i do it?

Comment: `Nz` does "work" for _Null_ values, thus the values of `delay_head` you believe are _Null_ only appear to be.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT IIf(IsNull(delay_head),0,delay_head) AS [delay_head_result]
FROM sumb
WHERE dep_reg='er';
```